# Ruby's body_permitted? method giving "NoMethodError"

Tags: ruby, nomethoderror

I was going through ruby's Net::HTTP class. Every time I run this code from Net::HTTP doc

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require 'net/http'
uri = URI('http://example.com/index.html')
res = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)

# Headers
res['Set-Cookie']            # => String
res.get_fields('set-cookie') # => Array
res.to_hash['set-cookie']    # => Array
puts "Headers: #{res.to_hash.inspect}"

# Status
puts res.code       # => '200'
puts res.message    # => 'OK'
puts res.class.name # => 'HTTPOK'

# Body
puts res.body if res.response_body_permitted?
```

I get this error

```
netHTTP.rb:18:in `<main>': undefined method `response_body_permitted?' for #<Net::HTTPOK 200 OK readbody=true> (NoMethodError)
```

Here is the response of code

```
Headers: {"accept-ranges"=>["bytes"], "cache-control"=>["max-age=604800"], "content-type"=>["text/html"], "date"=>["Sun, 07 Jun 2015 21:33:34 GMT"], "etag"=>["\"359670651\""], "expires"=>["Sun, 14 Jun 2015 21:33:34 GMT"], "last-modified"=>["Fri, 09 Aug 2013 23:54:35 GMT"], "server"=>["ECS (iad/18F0)"], "x-cache"=>["HIT"], "x-ec-custom-error"=>["1"], "content-length"=>["1270"]}
200
OK
Net::HTTPOK
netHTTP.rb:18:in `<main>': undefined method `response_body_permitted?' for #<Net::HTTPOK 200 OK readbody=true> (NoMethodError)
```

Is something wrong with my installation?

Comment: I checked response_body_permitted? method in source! It checks whether response has body or not. It should give true. Where i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the [source](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/fe8cc13685a847f5b4b687d9edb88f5bee58fd70/lib/net/http/response.rb#L19) and [docs](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTPResponse.html#method-c-body_permitted-3F) of Ruby 2.1.x (and 2.2.0), the method that you need is `body_permitted?` So try with `res.body_permitted?`.

You can search through the source of older versions of Ruby on GitHub, by referring to their different tags. Pretty sure there is no such method in `net/http` as `response_body_permitted?`.

**UPDATES**

I can see how the documentation on `body_permitted?` can be a bit misleading when it says,

> true if the response has a body.

First of all `body_permitted?` is a class method. So the correct way to use it is by doing something like:

```
irb(main)> Net::HTTPOK.body_permitted?
=> true
irb(main)> res.class.body_permitted?
=> true
```

Secondly, `body_permitted?` isn't telling you whether your particular response instance has a body. Instead, it's telling you whether the class of your response is **permitted** to have a body. Running these codes in irb will yield:

```
irb(main)> Net::HTTPOK.body_permitted?
=> true
irb(main)> Net::HTTPInformation.body_permitted?
=> false
```

Looking at the source of [HTTPOK](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/fe8cc13685a847f5b4b687d9edb88f5bee58fd70/lib/net/http/responses.rb#L36) and [HTTPInformation](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/fe8cc13685a847f5b4b687d9edb88f5bee58fd70/lib/net/http/responses.rb#L7) confirms our observation that `body_permitted?` is telling us whether body is permitted in each response class.

If you want to check if you response has a body, just do `res.body.nil?`. So something like:

```
puts res.body if res.class.body_permitted? && !res.body.nil?
```

Comment: First of all thanks for your reply! But still it showing `<main>: undefined method "body_permitted?" for #<Net::HTTPOK 200 OK readbody=true> (NoMethodError)`

Comment: @KumarSaurabh Sorry for the late replies. Please refer my updated answer. In a nutshell, `body_permitted?` is a class method, and it isn't doing what you thought it will.