# meaning of 'readbody' when when working with ruby http responses

Tags: ruby, http

What is `readbody` supposed to mean/indicate?

```
"#<Net::HTTPOK 200 OK readbody=true> "

"#<Net::HTTPUnauthorized 401 Unauthorized readbody=true>"
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30698704/rubys-body-permitted-method-giving-nomethoderror)

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a shot and guess that it means that they were able to read the body of the HTTP request.

There's the source code of the #read_body method in the link you provided.

https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/fe8cc13685a847f5b4b687d9edb88f5bee58fd70/lib/net/http/response.rb#L19

https://apidock.com/ruby/Net/HTTPResponse/read_body